# Bootstrap center align a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown button in the center of my page, but when I click the dropdown, the actual dropdown part is still on the left side of the page. What's the issue?

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 school-options-dropdown">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose a School
              <span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Add your school</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.school-options-dropdown {
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown {
    text-align:center;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working example

Answer (score 24):

You need to put the dropdown menu and the toggle button inside a `.btn-group`.

Also, Bootstrap provides the [`.text-center` property](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) to align the contents. This can be used on `.school-options-dropdown`, instead of manually adding CSS.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 school-options-dropdown text-center">
    <div class="dropdown btn-group">

      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose a School
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Add your school</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

I've found this when trying to solve similar problem.
Credit to [Vladimir Rodkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284255/vladimir-rodkin)

```
.dropdown-menu-center {
right: auto;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
-o-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
transform: translate(-50%, 0);}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/VovanR/2ao5b22h/

Comment: If you want use this with ver4, Try this..dropdown-menu-center {
  right: auto !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  top: 100% !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0) !important;
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, 0) !important;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0) !important;
}

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want change your html code, this is css will solve your problem:

```
.dropdown {text-align:center;}
.button, .dropdown-menu {margin:10px auto}
.dropdown-menu {width:200px; left:50%; margin-left:-100px;}
```

[Example on jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/studiosoldru/bvt7pusb/).

Comment: To avoid fixed width we can use `transform:translate`: https://jsfiddle.net/w3ujg7fq/

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to center align the contents of the menu, then

```
ul.dropdown-menu>li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

With a Bootstrap 5 you can use JavaScript to override Popper.js after page loads like:

```
new bootstrap.Dropdown(document.getElementById('dropdown_button'), {
    popperConfig: function () {
        return {placement: 'bottom'}
    }
});
```

---

Official documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#using-function-with-popperconfig

Here are placements you can override to:
https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/constructors/#options

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you add the alignment in the entire div class defining it